# How to make Google Sheets cell with a referencing formula to the whole column not display until updated

Tags: google-sheets, show-hide, calculated-columns, repeat

I have a couple of different docs I'm working with where I have formulas that, when I enter a payment made, will automatically update a financial column with balances due and amounts remaining, and I'm running into the same trouble on both.

One is tracking payments received for someone buying something from me and making payments that subtracts the payment from the balance due and shows the payment history, and the other is tracking medical expenses and showing the payment made, how much has been paid toward the deductible, and how much is remaining on the deductible.

All are simple sum formulas, and that's not the issue. The issue is that I don't want to see the same figure repeating all the way down my columns. I would like to find a way to make a value not actually "show up" until it has been updated, so the last figure displayed in the column is the one I can glance at to find the balance due, and it only displays there until I enter another payment, and then the cell below it "activates" and shows and is the one to look to, even though the whole column has the sum formula running to update as I enter more information. I hope that makes sense.

I'm presuming conditional formatting with changing the font to white? I just can't quite seem to get it. I'm sure I could do it one cell at a time to reference the cell above it, or even reference if the respective payment cell that will update that cell is blank, but that is a LOT of clicks and I just *know* there has to be a way to do an entire column at once.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Seeing the repeating numbers is just too much to take in for me.

Thank you!!

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH816.png)

[What I want it to look like, while maintaining the formula throughout the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuveB.png)

Comment: Can you maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet ?

Comment: `=IF(B2>0, <yourformula>, "")` assuming B is the amount paid column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$2,599.00` is in G3, please try clearing formatting from and selecting ColumnsF:G and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
=$B1=0
```

Then choose white font for formatting and <kbd>Done</kbd>.